# How to use multiple databases with ebean

Tags: java, database, postgresql, kotlin, ebean

I'm trying to use Ebean framework ORM queries to different postgres databases.
Following [these](https://ebean.io/docs/multi-database/) and [these](https://ebean.io/docs/database/postgres/) docs, queries to my single database works fine. But to address another one, I have to explicitly call it by DB.byName("name"). How can I avoid this explicit call?

To be clear, first example - as it is, second - as I want it to be:

1. `QDbEmailQueue(DB.byName("superadmin")).findCount()` works
2. `QDbEmailQueue().findCount()` throws next exception:

> ```
> Query threw SQLException:ERROR: relation "email_queue" does not exist
>   Position: 22 Bind values:[] Query was:select count(*) from email_queue t0
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ERROR: relation "email_queue" does not exist
>   Position: 22 Bind values:[] Query was:select count(*) from email_queue t0
> ```

In both cases I have my entity-class configured like that in kotlin:

```
@Entity
@DbName(value = "superadmin")
@Table(name = "email_queue")
class DbEmailQueue(
    @Id
    val emailQueueId: Int
    ...
): Model("superadmin")
```

And in both cases there is same configuration with EbeanConfigProvider.java like [here](https://ebean.io/docs/multi-database/):

```
public class EbeanConfigProvider implements ServerConfigProvider {

    public static final String SUPERADMIN = "superadmin";
    public static final String DB = "db";

    @Override
    public void apply(ServerConfig serverConfig) {

        DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig = serverConfig.getDataSourceConfig();
        dataSourceConfig
                .setUsername(Config.INSTANCE.getAppDbUserName())
                .setPassword(Config.INSTANCE.getAppDbUserPswd());

        switch (serverConfig.getName()) {
            case DB: {
                serverConfig.setDefaultServer(true);
                dataSourceConfig.setUrl(Config.INSTANCE.getAppDbHostUrl() + Config.INSTANCE.getAppDbName());
                break;
            }
            case SUPERADMIN: {
                serverConfig.setDefaultServer(false);
                dataSourceConfig.setUrl(Config.INSTANCE.getAppDbHostUrl() + Config.INSTANCE.getSuperadminDbName());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and application.yaml according to this [doc](https://ebean.io/docs/database/postgres/):

```
ebean:
  dbSchema: public  # use this schema rather than public
  migration:
    run: false       # run database migrations on startup
  search:
    packages: om.bo.mypackage.db
    querybean-packages: om.bo.mypackage.db.query

datasource:
  db:
    driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    default: true

  superadmin:
    driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    dbName: superadmin
    default: false
```

Comment: What is the version of Ebean you are using?  With @DbName the query bean generated will use that name to obtain the correct Database.  Have a look at the generated source for `QDbEmailQueue()`

Comment: @RobBygrave ebean 12.1.10. Yes, It has generated constructor with provided name of database, but It still does not work

Comment: @RobBygrave thanks for the tip. I have tried new version previously, but it looks like I got the bad one. Now I just tried every version after 12.1.10 and found that 2 of them work as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update ebean version.
I had ebean 12.1.10.
At 12.1.11 problem still exists, but at versions 12.1.12 and 12.1.13 everything works as I want (starting from 12.2.1 problem appears aggain with different exception)